# rest api codeigniter result missing column

Tags: php, api, rest, codeigniter

I'm having trouble with rest API result in Codeigniter
in my local computer the result are fine

```
[{"id"="1","organisasi"="Why","status"="1"}
```

but when I deploy in on-line server, the result become like this:

```
[{"organisasi"="1","status"="Why",""="1"}
```

1 column missing from the result in on-line server

here my script for select

```
function select_post(){ 
    if(!$this->post('table')){ 
        $this->response('no table'); return 0;
    }
    if($this->post('table')=='user'){
    $pos1=false;
    $pos2=false;
    if($this->post('where') ){
        $pos1 = stripos($this->post('where'),'password');
    }
    if($this->post('select')){
        $pos2 = stripos($this->post('select'),'password');
    }
    if($pos1 !== false || $pos2 !== false){
        $this->response('select password is prohibited');return 0;
    }
}
if($this->post('join')&&$this->post('on')) 
    $this->db->join($this->post('join'),$this->post('on'));
    if($this->post('table')=='user'){
        if($this->post('where')) {
            $this->db->where($this->post('where').'AND role = 1');
        } else {
            $this->db->where('role = 1');
        }  
    } else {
        if($this->post('where')) $this->db->where($this->post('where'));
    }
  
  
if($this->post('select')) 
    $this->db->select($this->post('select'));
    if($this->post('limit')){
        $this->db->limit($this->post('limit'));
    }else{
        $this->db->limit(10);
    }
    
if($this->post('limit')&&$this->post('offset')) 
    $this->db->limit($this->post('limit'),$this->post('offset'));
    if($this->post('order')) 
        $this->db->order_by($this->post('order'));
        $query = $this->db->get($this->post('table'));
        $result=$query->result();
        $txtOut="[";
        foreach($result as $row){
            $txtOut.="{";
            $row=(array)$row;
            foreach($row as $col){
                if(key($row)!=='password'&&key($row)!=='key'){
                    $txtOut.='"'.key($row).'"="'.$col.'",';
                }
                next($row);
            }
            $txtOut=rtrim($txtOut,",");
            $txtOut.="},";
        }
        $txtOut=rtrim($txtOut, ",");
        $this->logging('select',json_encode($_POST),$txtOut."]");
        echo $txtOut."]";
}
```

Any ideas where i do wrong ?

Comment: There can be some change in your local and live server db. There is a column missing and also values are one step ahead. Also why are you creating JSON yourself when you can simply create an array and can json_encode it?